# When a force is applied continuously on a two body system such that both of them touch each other why do they move with same acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

If we take two objects such that both of them are in contact,then a force is continuously applied on any of the object both of them will move with a constant and equal acceleration.Why does that happen? Why their acceleration aren't unequal?

Why does the first object don't exert the same amount of force on the 2nd? Is it that the first body is actually applying the same force but due to our continuous application of force we don't observe that?

Comment: Are you thinking of two objects in contact, where you push on one and it pushed on the other? They stay in contact, and move at the same speed and stay the same distance apart? If so, it is because they always have the same velocity, and therefore the same changes in velocity.

Comment: yes they are in contact

Comment: But why does that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that both bodies are rigid( there is no deformation and the distance between any 2 points is constant)

As you start pushing the first bodily, it gains some acceleration and pushes into the second body, exerting a contact force on it and causing it to accelerate.

At the atomic level, contact forces are electrostatic in nature and as a very crude approximation, can be though of glad springs. The harder you push, telhe more compressed they get and the greater the force exerted on you.

The force between the 2 bodies increases until the acceleration (and velocity) of the 2 bodies become equal. At this point, there is no further relative motion between them, so the distance between them and this the force they exert on each other do not change

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

What is contact ? contact is enough distance between atoms of 2 body so first body can apply certain amount of force on second body(same as second applies on first),which will give it same acceleration as first one.If there will be lets say differantial velocity difference,it will result change in differantial distance between objects or vice versa.Negative change will give compression and rise in reaction force consequently balancing second ones acceleration for example.Im assuming first object has infinite mass or some main drive force which is big enough.